# Read/Mount a csv file inside train.py of Azure ML Pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

We are collecting data from Eventhub and AppInsight and storing it in azure blob. By using AzureML pipeline I want to pass my dataset into train.py going through two different logics(one for ml, another for fraud analysis).

But I couldnt read the csv file for further processing from inside the `train.py`

This is my `train.py` which is running through `PythonScriptStep` in Azure Machine Learning Pipeline

```
import argparse
import os
import pandas as pd

print("In train.py")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("train")

parser.add_argument("--input_data", type=str, help="input data")
parser.add_argument("--output_train", type=str, help="output_train directory")

args = parser.parse_args()

print("Argument 1: %s" % args.input_data)
df = pd.read_csv(args.input_data)
print(df.head())

print("Argument 2: %s" % args.output_train)

if not (args.output_train is None):
    os.makedirs(args.output_train, exist_ok=True)
    print("%s created" % args.output_train)
```

And this is the code for running the Pipeline

```
ws = Workspace.from_config()
def_blob_store = Datastore(ws, "basic_data_store")
aml_compute_target = "test-cluster"
try:
    aml_compute = AmlCompute(ws, aml_compute_target)
    print("found existing compute target.")
except ComputeTargetException:
    print("Error")

source_directory = './train'

blob_input_data = DataReference(
    datastore=def_blob_store,
    data_reference_name="device_data",
    path_on_datastore="_fraud_data/test.csv")
trainStep = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name="train.py", 
    arguments=["--input_data", blob_input_data, "--output_train", processed_data1],
    inputs=[blob_input_data],
    outputs=[processed_data1],
    compute_target=aml_compute, 
    source_directory=source_directory,
    runconfig=run_config
)
pipeline1 = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=[compareStep])
pipeline_run1 = Experiment(ws, 'Data_dependency').submit(pipeline1)
```

Down below in the output trace, you can see the output `Argument 1` is printing the path of the file

`Argument 1: /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv`

So I have successfully pass the dataset but cant read the file inside train.py on line `pd.read_csv(args.input_data)`.  It is showing

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv'`

this is the full trace from `70_driver_log.txt` which I have downloaded from azureml log,

```
Preparing to call script [ train.py ] with arguments: ['--input_data', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv', '--output_train', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/processed_data1']
After variable expansion, calling script [ train.py ] with arguments: ['--input_data', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv', '--output_train', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/processed_data1']

In train.py
Argument 1: /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv


The experiment failed. Finalizing run...
Cleaning up all outstanding Run operations, waiting 300.0 seconds
1 items cleaning up...
Cleanup took 0.001172780990600586 seconds
Starting the daemon thread to refresh tokens in background for process with pid = 136
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(args.input_data) #str()
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_eb042e80b9a6abdb5821a78683153a38/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_eb042e80b9a6abdb5821a78683153a38/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_eb042e80b9a6abdb5821a78683153a38/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_eb042e80b9a6abdb5821a78683153a38/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_eb042e80b9a6abdb5821a78683153a38/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 689, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv' does not exist: b'/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/pipeline-shohoz/azureml/d92be2ab-e63f-4883-a14b-a64fa5bb431d/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv'
```

I have tried the relative path

`azureml/8d2b7bee-6cc5-4c8c-a685-1300a240de8f/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv`

and also the Uri

`wasbs://shohoz-container@shohozds.blob.core.windows.net/azureml/azureml/8d2b7bee-6cc5-4c8c-a685-1300a240de8f/mounts/basic_data_store/_fraud_data/test.csv`

but ending with the same `FileNotFoundError` result. I am banging my head on the wall for last 3-4 days. Any help will save my brain.

Comment: Any chance you recall how you fixed this? I'm having the same issue. Explicitly passing in the mount path as prescribed by Ram-msft (in the arguments field) did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can include a registered dataset in a PythonScriptStep by using a PipelineDataset object - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.pipelinedataset?view=azure-ml-py for more details and an example.

[image]

Comment: where should I pass this `script_params`